# don't understand the reason for error 91 - new to vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add the cells in the rows ranging 6 to 80, columns ranging 4 to 23  from sheet 7 to sheets.count and dump the added value in sheet 5. This is what I did so far with the help of another SO member. I can't figure out the reason for error 91.

Error is on this line: `ar(i, j) = ar(i, j) + ws.Cells(i, j)`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsSummation As Worksheet
    Dim startRow As Long, StartCol As Long
    Dim endRow As Long, endCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ar(6 To 80, 4 To 23) As Variant
    Dim myTotal As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    x = 7

    '~~> Start row and start column
    startRow = 6: StartCol = 4
    endRow = 6: endCol = 4
    'Set myTotal = Sheets.Count 'total sheet count

    '~~> Summary sheet
    'Set wsSummation = Sheet5

    '~~> Looping through each worksheet from Summation to end
    For x = 7 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        '~~> Check if it is not the summary sheet
        'If ws.Name <> wsSummation.Name Then
            '~~> Loop through the row and columns and
            '~~> Store it in an array
            For i = startRow To endRow
                For j = StartCol To endCol
                  ar(i, j) = ar(i, j) + ws.Cells(i, j)
                Next j
            Next i
        'End If
    Next x

    '~~> Write array to summary sheet
    wsSummation.Range("D6").Resize(UBound(ar), UBound(ar)).Value = ar
End Sub
```

Comment: You have commented out the line "Set wsSummation = Sheet5". I'm assuming you will also want to change that line to be something like "Set wsSummation = Worksheets("Sheet5")"

Comment: Error 91 only ever has one reason to be raised: you're making a member call on an object reference that hasn't been initialized. See [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27750/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set#t=201706301632532828782).

Comment: @Mat'sMug: I went into debug mode and the error seems to be occuring in this line ar(i, j) = ar(i, j) + ws.Cells(i, j). Do i have to predeclare "ar"? Or did I write the syntax wrongly for ws.cells(i,j)?

Comment: @davidmneedham: Uncommenting that line led to subscript out of range error

Comment: `ws` is declared as a `Worksheet` object reference. Where is that object reference `Set`? You're referring to `ws` before it's assigned, the reference is `Nothing`. You can't do member calls on `Nothing`.

Comment: As for "subscript out of range", that means there's no sheet named "Sheet5" in the `Worksheets` collection.

Comment: Your intention seems to be to iterate through the worksheets. Unfortunately, you never communicated your intention to VBA by setting `ws` equal to successive worksheets. You need something like `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x)`, just after the line which begins `For x = 7`

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Yes, that was my mistake.. That is what I was looking too figure out. Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @JohnColeman : Yes, that was my mistake.. The program works now without any issues.. Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write a few lines to help you understand what @Mat's Mug trying to explain.

You are looping through the Workbook's worksheets, but you don't set your `ws` object to the worksheet you are trying to loop. So, afterwards, you are reaching this line `ar(i, j) = ar(i, j) + ws.Cells(i, j)` you are getting an error, since `ws` was never set-up properly.

Try the ***Code*** loop below :

```
'~~> Looping through each worksheet from Summation to end
For x = 7 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ' ==== YOU NEED to SET the WORKSHEET OBJECT FIRST, BEFORE YOU USE IT
    '~~> Check if it is not the summary sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x)
    With ws ' have a with statement to simplify your nested code
        'If ws.Name <> wsSummation.Name Then
        '~~> Loop through the row and columns and
        '~~> Store it in an array
        For i = startRow To endRow
            For j = StartCol To endCol
                ar(i, j) = ar(i, j) + .Cells(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
        'End If
    End With
Next x
```